# How to use web component converted from react component using react-to-webcomponent library in other projects react/vue/svelte/etc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component, package.json, rollup

My web component is working fine If I add the react and react-dom as peer dependencies in other react projects but because I want this component to also work in other frameworks like Vue/svelte/vanilla etc., therefore, I added react and react-dom to dependencies but then I am getting cannot read property use ref of undefined react_min_production kind of error in the browser and it crashes.

So how can I achieve this?
Or do I have to use the react component itself for the react project and the web component for the rest of the projects?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a some code so users can see what you have tried already

Comment: I got it working by adding the react and react-dom as dependency so it will include it in the bundle no matter which version other projects are using. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by adding the react and react-dom as dependency so it will include it in the bundle no matter which version other projects are using. Thank you!